# $\int_0 ^ \infty \frac{\cos(3x)}{2x^2 + 4} dx$ using residue calculus

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to calculate $\int_0 ^ \infty \frac{\cos(3x)}{2x^2 + 4} dx$ using residue calculus.

**My work so far**

My contour will be defined as combination of two other contours:

$C := [0, R]$ and $C_R$ its a semicircle with $Im(z) > 0$ (above x axis).

$$f(z) = \frac{\cos(3z)}{2(z^2 + 2)} = \frac{\cos(3z)}{2(z^2 - 2i^2)} = \frac{\cos(3z)}{2(z - \sqrt 2 i)(z + \sqrt 2 i)}$$

We have two poles with rank $1$ in $\sqrt 2i$ and $-\sqrt 2i$. Out of those two, only $\sqrt 2i$ belongs to our contour, so if we calculate residue:

$$res_{\sqrt 2i}f = \lim_{z \rightarrow \sqrt 2i} \frac{\cos(3z)}{2(z + \sqrt 2 i)}= \frac{\cos(3 \sqrt 2) i }{ 4\sqrt 2i} $$

Moreover we know that $\cos(3 \sqrt 2 i ) = \frac{e^{- 3 \sqrt 2} + e^{3 \sqrt 2}}{2}$

Finally our integral is equal to $2\pi i \cdot res_{\sqrt 2i} f$:

$$\int_0 ^ \infty \frac{\cos(3x)}{2x^2 + 4} dx = \frac{e^{3 \sqrt 2} + e^{- 3 \sqrt 2}}{4 \sqrt 2} \pi$$

Whereas wolfram alpha suggests that our integral should be equal to:

$$\int_0 ^ \infty \frac{\cos(3x)}{2x^2 + 4} dx = \frac{e^{-3\sqrt2} \pi}{4 \sqrt 2}$$

I want to ask you - where do I have the mistake? Why term $e^{3 \sqrt 2}$ should vanish?

Comment: Asked zillions of times. Everytime missing the fact that $\cos z$ (and the like) behaves really bad when *complex* values of $z$ are considered. (Cf. $e^{iz}$).

Comment: The mistake is in the parts you left out above. How did you show that $\int_{C_R}f\to0$??? (that's not true with things set up the way you set them up...)

Answer (score 1):

You have\begin{align}\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(3x)}{2x^2+4}\,\mathrm dx&=\frac14\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(3x)}{x^2+2}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\frac14\operatorname{Re}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{3ix}}{x^2+2}\,\mathrm dx\right).\end{align}Now, for each $R>0$, define$$\begin{array}{rccc}\alpha_R\colon&[0,\pi]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&t&\mapsto&Re^{it}\end{array}$$and define $f(z)=\frac{e^{3iz}}{z^2+2}$. Then$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\alpha_R}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=0.\tag1$$Then\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{3ix}}{x^2+2}\,\mathrm dx&=\lim_{R\to0}\left(\int_{-R}^Rf(z)\,\mathrm dz+\int_{\alpha_R}f(z)\,\mathrm dz\right)\\&=2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=\sqrt2\,i}\left(\frac{e^{3iz}}{z^2+2}\right)\\&=2\pi i\left(-\frac{i e^{-3 \sqrt{2}}}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)\\&=\frac{e^{-3 \sqrt{2}} \pi }{\sqrt{2}}.\end{align}Therefore$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(3x)}{2x^2+4}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{e^{-3\sqrt2}\pi}{4\sqrt2}.$$Note that, in order to use this approach, I had to check that $(1)$ holds. This is not true for your function $f$.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using residue theorem. The whole loop integral is equal to that:

$$ \int_{\text{semi circle arc} } + \int_{R} = 2\pi i \sum \text{residues enclosed by loop} * \text{winding number of residue}$$

You've only considered the integral over R

Comment: Isn't this true that $\int_{\textrm{semi circle arc}}$ should vanish as $R \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @Lucian: No. Check this *yourself*.